# Arcade game with a sit-down cabinet and vibrating seat

Tags: identify-this-game

I don't know the name of an arcade game; can someone please help?

When you go all the way to the ground, your ship turns into a car and your seat vibrates.  In the last stage, your ship turns into another special, different ship.  The beginning story says you're trying to save a professor.  You start at 'A', then go to either 'B' or 'C' on the map.

It was post 1985.

Comment: can you tell us more about the graphics, was it 1980 or more post 1985 16-bit?

Comment: It was post 1985. Not sure about the graphics. Even when you get hit the seat vibrates.

Comment: Was it in an arcade, if yes, what country? How did the shell look? Real seat, plastic seat or wooden bench?

Comment: Any idea on 2d overhead or side view versus 3d into-the-screen?

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to say it was Taito's [Night Striker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LHtKIVNudc) from 1989.

Had a sit-down cockpit cab, plot has a scientist and his daughter being abducted, it has Out Run style branching A-B-C style stages, your ship seems to  be able to descend and drive on the road, and in the last stage you seem to have some sort of co-pilot with you, if not a different ship.